# Inserting button with javascript/web component

Tags: magento2, javascript, custom-button

I am a complete newbie to Magento development and I am CSE student working as an intern.
My question is as follows:
Is it possible to add a button to a Magento 2 page with JavaScript and web components? If yes, how and what are the basic concepts I need to understand, and are there any tutorials or resources you can recommend to help me accomplish this task?
(This is my first question)